# WSO2 DSS Timezone issue

Tags: sql-server, datetime, wso2, wso2-data-services-server

We are trying to retrieve data from Sql Server. In the response DSS is converting date into UTC timezone.

in sql server date = 2008-06-30 00:00:00.000

but in the DSS results date = "2008-06-29T17:00:00.000-07:00"

As per below link we tried to disable the UTC format in the DSS Server (windows) but it is not working.

WSO2 mentioned to false below property but that is not exists in the wso2server.bat

-Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true

https://docs.wso2.com/display/DSS351/Timestamp+Conversion+for+RDBMS. 
We tried to add that property value with false but it is not working.

We want exact sql server date. Can someone please let me know how to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the wso2server.bat we added this property -Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true in the below location which resolved our issue. set CMD_LINE_ARGS=-Xbootclasspath/a:%CARBON_XBOOTCLASSPATH% -Xms256m -Xmx1024m -XX:MaxPermSize=256m -XX:+HeapDumpOnOutOfMemoryError -XX:HeapDumpPath="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\logs\heap-dump.hprof"  -Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote -classpath %CARBON_CLASSPATH% %JAVA_OPTS% -Djava.endorsed.dirs=%JAVA_ENDORSED% -Dcarbon.registry.root=/ -Dcarbon.home="%CARBON_HOME%" -Dwso2.server.standalone=true -Djava.command="%JAVA_HOME%\bin\java" -Djava.opts="%JAVA_OPTS%" -Djava.io.tmpdir="%CARBON_HOME%\tmp" -Dcatalina.base="%CARBON_HOME%\lib\tomcat" -Dwso2.carbon.xml=%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf\carbon.xml -Dwso2.registry.xml="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf\registry.xml" -Dwso2.user.mgt.xml="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf\user-mgt.xml" -Dwso2.transports.xml="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf\mgt-transports.xml" -Djava.util.logging.config.file="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf\etc\logging-bridge.properties" -Djava.util.logging.manager=org.apache.juli.ClassLoaderLogManager -Dcarbon.config.dir.path="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf"  -Dcomponents.repo="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\components" -Dconf.location="%CARBON_HOME%\repository\conf" -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.file="%CARBON_HOME%\lib\transactions.properties" -Dcom.atomikos.icatch.hide_init_file_path="true" -Dorg.apache.jasper.compiler.Parser.STRICT_QUOTE_ESCAPING=false -Dorg.apache.jasper.runtime.BodyContentImpl.LIMIT_BUFFER=true -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.authentication=simple -Dcom.sun.jndi.ldap.connect.pool.timeout=3000 -Dorg.terracotta.quartz.skipUpdateCheck=true -Dcarbon.classpath=%CARBON_CLASSPATH% -Dfile.encoding=UTF8 -DworkerNode=false -Dorg.wso2.ignoreHostnameVerification=true **-Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true**

Answer (score 1):

The -Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true (There was a documentation issue and now it is fixed.) has to be defined as a Java System Property in the wso2server.bat or wso2server.sh script. This is not added by default. Please note that this is supported from DSS 3.5.1 version.

Comment: Thank you for the update. But how to define that in the wso2server.bat file? Can you please give me an example configuration in the bat file.Is it something like this in the line set JAVA_OPTS=-Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=%DEBUG_PORT%,**-Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=true** ??

Comment: Is there any update on this request please ? Can someone please please help us to fix this.

Comment: I added below command in the wso2.bat file **set JAVA_OPTS=-Ddss.legacy.timezone.mode=false -Xdebug -Xnoagent -Djava.compiler=NONE -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=y,address=%DEBUG_PORT%**  but still in my out put i am getting UTC timezone in my response **<date_created>2004-05-28T03:52:43.167-07:00</date_created>**

Comment: What is the DSS version?

Comment: Hi Chanikag, version is : wso2dss-3.5.1 . This issue is pending for long time . Please help me get it resolved